# A different variation of the triangle inequality.

Tags: inequality

> Prove that:
>
> $|z-1|\leq|\sqrt{z^2-1}|<|z+1|$ for R(z)>0

I tried using the general triangle inequality $|z_1|-|z_2|\leq |z_1+z_2|\leq|z_1|+|z_2|$, but I can't seem to get this working.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: z^2 - 1 = (z - 1)(z + 1)

Comment: z + 1 > z - 1, so you should go from there

Comment: @QuantumFool Okay, I did. But somehow I get that (z+1)>(z-1) on both sides. Is that right?

Comment: Are we working in Complex Analysis / working with complex numbers? I hadn't been thinking about that

Comment: If not, then subtract by z to get 1 > -1 which is true. If we are working with complex stuff, then we can't compare complex numbers directly.

Comment: Just magnitudes.

Comment: @QuantumFool It is complex analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that if $\operatorname{Re}(z) > 0$ then $|z-1| \lt |z+1|$.

This is obvious geometrically, since all points in the right half-plane $x > 0$ are closer to point $(1,0)$ on the $x$ axis than they are to its symmetric across the $y$ axis $(-1,0$). For a formal proof:

$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Re}(z) > 0 & \iff z + \overline z \gt 0  \\
 & \iff z \overline z - (z + \overline z) + 1 \lt z \overline z + (z + \overline z) + 1 \\
 & \iff (z-1)(\overline z - 1) \lt (z+1)(\overline z + 1) \\
 & \iff |z-1|^2 \lt |z+1|^2
\end{align}
$$

When $z \ne 1$ the above gives the following inequalities, which imply the ones to prove:

$$
\begin{align}
\left| \frac{z-1}{z+1}\right| \lt 1 \lt \left| \frac{z+1}{z-1} \right| & \quad\iff\quad |z-1|^2  \lt |z^2-1| \lt |z+1|^2
\end{align}
$$

Finally, when $z=1$ the given inequalities trivially hold, with equality for the LHS one.